# Woocommerce how to add attribute suffix to product name

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

We sell rugs and for our customer it is necessary to instantly see the size of each rug while browsing through our shop.

Currently a product just has the Product name displayed.
Just when you open the product you can see in the size in the product details.

I want that after the name the length and width is being displayed like: Name 150x72cm

Answer (score 0):

You can use Advanced Custom Fields to add a text field to your Product. Then use WooCommerce hooks to add the custom field to your product name.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
function customize_shop_page_product_title() {
    $field_rug_size = get_field('rug_size');
    echo '<h3 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">' . get_the_title() . " (" . $field_rug_size .')</h3>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','customize_shop_page_product_title');
```